# how i can find some variable closest in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i want select variable inside tag `script` but closest...

```
<div id='Auth-Sec'>
<div class='LinkList'>
<div class='widget-content'>
<i class='get-rank'/>
<i class='get-about'/>
<b:tag name='script' type='text/javascript'>
var snapAuthor=AuthorsInfo.filter(function(a){return a.name===&#39;<data:title/>&#39;})[0];

if(snapAuthor!==undefined){
snapAuthor.provided=true;

<b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
<b:if cond='data:link.name contains &quot;-ad&quot;'>
snapAuthor[&#39;<data:link.name/>&#39;]=&#39;<data:link.target.jsEscaped/>&#39;;
<b:else/>
<b:switch var='data:link.name'>
<b:case value='rank'/>snapAuthor.rank=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
<b:case value='about'/>snapAuthor.about=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
<b:default/>snapAuthor.links[&#39;<data:link.name/>&#39;]=&#39;<data:link.target/>&#39;;
</b:switch>

</b:if>
</b:loop>
}</b:tag>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>



$("#Auth-Sec .LinkList").each(function(){
var e = $(this),
nameClass = e.find(".widget-content"),
getDataTitle = e.find(nameClass).prev('.headline').data('title'),
getRankName = e.find(nameClass).nextAll('script');

var gatVaribale = $(getRankName).find(snapAuthor['rank']) // i want get it

snapAuthor.name = getDataTitle;
var setSnapName = snapAuthor.name,
setSnapRank = snapAuthor['rank'],
setSnapAbout = snapAuthor['about'];

if (setSnapName === AuthorName){

console.log(gatVaribale)

}

});
```

Comment: You don't need to do `e.find(nameClass).prev`, it should just be `nameClass.prev`

Comment: i want select closest snapAuthor['rank'] inside script how do it ?

Comment: closest in jQuery means to search for a containing element that matches a selector.

Comment: I think you want `e.find(":contains(snapAuthor.rank)")` but I'm not really sure I understand what you're doing.

Comment: This is a tool whose purpose is to have multiple authors in Blogger, and I have many functions that work with each author separately, but I want to choose the closest variable after the specified element.